# Writing query with parameters to avoid SQL Injections

Tags: sql-injection, parameterized, prepared-statement

I have done that before, but in this case I have an `insert into table` query where value of the column of the target table comes as a result from another query. Having that, I'm not sure if my `parametarized query` is formatted the right way.

Here is an original query without before `Sql Injection` fix:

```
cmd.CommandText += "insert into controlnumber (controlnumber, errorid) 
values ('" + ControlNumber + "', (select errorid from error where 
errordescription = '" + ErrorDescription + "' and errortype = '" + 
ErrorType + "' + and applicationid = " + ApplicationID + " and statusid =
" + StatusID + " and userid = " + UserID + " and errortime = '" + 
ErrorTime + "');";
```

This is the query after I tried to fix `Sql Injection`:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into ControlTable(ControlNumber, ErrorID)
values (@ControlNum, (select errorid from error where errordescription = 
@ErrorDescription and errortype = @errorType and applicationid = 
@ApplicationID and statusid = @StatusID and userid = @UserID and 
errortime = @ErrorTime)"
```

This is where I add parameters:

.....

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ErrorDescription ", ErrorDesc);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ControlNum", cntNumber);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@errorType",ErrorType);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplicationID",AppID);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusID",StatusID);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID",UserID);
```

....
I'm just wondering if my `CommandText` is formatted the right way.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into ControlTable(ControlNumber, ErrorID)
select @ControlNum, errorid from error where errordescription = 
@ErrorDescription and errortype = @errorType and applicationid = 
@ApplicationID and statusid = @StatusID and userid = @UserID and 
errortime = @ErrorTime)"
```

When using INSERT INTO SELECT FROM, you do not use keyword VALUES. The syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(columns) SELECT ... FROM TABLE2
```

Comment: Thank you, but in my case I do not use `INSERT INTO TABLE(columns) SELECT ... FROM TABLE2`, my second column is a result of select statement

Comment: I doubt that's going to work. You will most likely need to incorporate your first column value into your select

Comment: @ElenaDBA Yes and no. OP's query _can_ work if the number of items in `error` that match is <= 1 (assuming `ControlTable` allows nulls for `ErrorID` - otherwise match count must == 1). If the match count is > 1, it will always fail.